# Enable a button on entering text in input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to enable a button only when a text is entered on an input field. So far I have this code on my app.js

```
.controller("EnableDisable", function(){
  $scope.editableInput = false;
})

.directive("inputDisabled", function(){
  return function(scope, element, attrs){
    scope.$watch(attrs.inputDisabled, function(val){
      if(val)
        element.removeAttr("disabled");
      else
        element.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
  }
});
```

This is the view implementation :

```
<div ng-controller="EnableDisable">
<input type="text" input-disabled="editableInput" />
<button ng-click="editableInput = !editableInput">enable/disable</button>
      </div>
```

This is the plunk url:
https://plnkr.co/edit/bHtZJ1H5JvM2XTuhft6J?p=preview
Presently when I launch the app, the button is not disabled by default.
Please with the above challenge how can I make the button clickable (receive events)when a text is entered on the input field.
Kindly assist!

Comment: just a question.. Why are you not using `form` validations

Comment: please create JSFiddle of your code

Comment: what do you mean trigger the button?

Comment: Here is plnk I have made:  https://plnkr.co/edit/bHtZJ1H5JvM2XTuhft6J?p=preview

Comment: Why you want do it using directory?Other not acceptable?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: My question has tag in it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
controller("EnableDisable", function($scope){
  $scope.textEntered = "";
});
```

HTML :

```
<button ng-disabled="!textEntered">enable/disable</button>
```

Please refer [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/z8EGr6XUKuKUmGz1EszI?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with Angular.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="textEntered" />
<button ng-disabled="!textEntered">Continue</button>
```

Comment: The button is clickable even when text has not been entered on the input field.... Check my plunk

Comment: @JnG check this plunk I've corrected pretty much every thing.. [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/zbZNjy5KMQdByJJvQjlP?p=preview) and included Nishi's answer

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set initial scope value like this.Note that I have set it false so condition will negate and make button disable on page load.Then I have set a watch on input value accordingly toggled the scope value.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller("EnableDisable",  function(){    
  $scope.textEntered=false;

  $scope.$watch($scope.textEntered,function(v)
  {
   if(v)
   {
     $scope.textEntered=true;
   }
   else
   {
     $scope.textEntered=false;
   }
  }
  );
});
```

and html is -

```
<input type="text" ng-model="textEntered" />
<button ng-disabled="!textEntered">Continue</button>
```

<kbd>https://plnkr.co/edit/o1Im8MSXbEa8kyqPqBB9?p=preview</kbd>

Comment: Please can you make a jsfiddle or plunk of this answer