# Having a button appear when a Text Input field is not empty (Kotlin in Android)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to enable a button on entering text in an input field. Something similar to this:

[Enable a button on entering text in input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35199701/enable-a-button-on-entering-text-in-input-field)

...but in Kotlin.

My current code looks like :

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    listOf(textInput1, textInput2, textInput3).map {
            it.setOnEditorActionListener() { v, _, _ ->
                showButtons(it)
                true
            }
    }
}
```

and the function is empty:

```
fun showButtons(textInputHolder: TextInputEditText){
    if (textInputHolder == textInput1 || textInput2) {
         button1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        button2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to show different buttons depending on which one of the list(textInput1, textInput2, textInput3) is being edited.

Thanks,

F

Comment: An empty function will obviously not work. What's the exact problem you are facing when writing it.

Comment: @Henry I edited the question. Something like what I have shown, but the current code doesn't work

Comment: and "doesn't work" means what? What did you expect to happen and what happened instead?

Comment: it doesn't compile